# MvcSiteMapProvider includes extra route values

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2, mvcsitemapprovider

I have an action method that can take an optional id parameter.

```
 public ActionResult Details(int id = 0) {...}
```

and a site node that should link to the action method with empty id.

```
<mvcSiteMapNode title="This Object" controller="MyController" action="Details" />
```

Unfortunately, things don't work out as expected. Most of the time the generated link is /MyController/Details as desired, but if I am currently in "/MyContoller/Details/99", the generated link is /MyContoller/Details**/99**.

Question: How can I get mvcSiteMapNode to ignore the id param when generating a link?

Thanks,
Duffy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I didn't realize I could just add random extra parameters to the mvcsitemapnode. (Mvcsitemap is great but the documentation could do more than just repeat the names of each function...) I ended up just passing in a parameter that effectively overwrote the "99" with a neutral value. Probably not the prettiest approach but solved the problem.

Comment: where did u add the parameter. I am having similar problem.

Comment: just add an attribute in the mvcsitemapnode element in your sitemap

<mvcSiteMapNode title="Warn" controller="Logging" action="Manage" extra="somevalue"/>